# Django:Remove superuser checkbox from Django admin panel when login staff users

Tags: django, django-admin

I need to edit the django admin panel. In my application, superuser can add users and can assign the privileges. when super user add staff user like HR manager, application should allow to add users. it works. but I need do is when staff user log to the admin panel hide the superuser status bar. how can I do this? what Django admin file should I change? and How?

Comment: Hey @Lahiruzz, the information you provided might be a bit vague. Can you describe to me what the "superuser status bar" is? Is it the default teal(ish) bar at the top of the entire admin panel?

Comment: when user create we can give permissions in django admin panel. under permission you can see superuser checkbox, I  want to hide that checkbox when staff user login to system but not superuser.

Comment: http://www.mahner.org/posts/separating-staff-and-user-accounts-in-djangos-admin/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to remove the "is superuser" checkbox from the Django Admin "Edit User" page, it's important to understand where and how the "superuser" checkbox comes from.

Under your django installation a file called `django.contrib.auth.forms` calls the class `class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):`. The model file it reads is `django.contrib.auth.models` for the `class User(models.Model):` class. Essentially the `django.contrib.auth.admin` file reads passes the fields found in the models as manual `fieldset` parameters.

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),

    (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),        
    (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                   'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
    (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
)
```

The best way to remove the field is by updating a local "admin.py" file to "unregister" and "register" the User model and remove the "superuser" field from the fieldset.

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import (UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm,
    AdminPasswordChangeForm)
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.views.decorators.debug import sensitive_post_parameters

csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

### Unregister the existing User model from the admin
admin.site.unregister(User)

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    add_form_template = 'admin/auth/user/add_form.html'
    change_user_password_template = None
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),

        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),        

        ###################################
        #### CHANGE THIS RIGHT HERE #######        
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ####################################

        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    form = UserChangeForm
    add_form = UserCreationForm
    change_password_form = AdminPasswordChangeForm
    list_display = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'is_active')
    search_fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    ordering = ('username',)
    filter_horizontal = ('user_permissions',)

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Use special form during user creation
        """
        defaults = {}
        if obj is None:
            defaults.update({
                'form': self.add_form,
                'fields': admin.util.flatten_fieldsets(self.add_fieldsets),
            })
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **defaults)

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.conf.urls import patterns
        return patterns('',
            (r'^(\d+)/password/$',
             self.admin_site.admin_view(self.user_change_password))
        ) + super(UserAdmin, self).get_urls()

    @sensitive_post_parameters()
    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.commit_on_success
    def add_view(self, request, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        # It's an error for a user to have add permission but NOT change
        # permission for users. If we allowed such users to add users, they
        # could create superusers, which would mean they would essentially have
        # the permission to change users. To avoid the problem entirely, we
        # disallow users from adding users if they don't have change
        # permission.
        if not self.has_change_permission(request):
            if self.has_add_permission(request) and settings.DEBUG:
                # Raise Http404 in debug mode so that the user gets a helpful
                # error message.
                raise Http404(
                    'Your user does not have the "Change user" permission. In '
                    'order to add users, Django requires that your user '
                    'account have both the "Add user" and "Change user" '
                    'permissions set.')
            raise PermissionDenied
        if extra_context is None:
            extra_context = {}
        defaults = {
            'auto_populated_fields': (),
            'username_help_text': self.model._meta.get_field('username').help_text,
        }
        extra_context.update(defaults)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url,
                                               extra_context)

    @sensitive_post_parameters()
    def user_change_password(self, request, id, form_url=''):
        if not self.has_change_permission(request):
            raise PermissionDenied
        user = get_object_or_404(self.queryset(request), pk=id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.change_password_form(user, request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                msg = ugettext('Password changed successfully.')
                messages.success(request, msg)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('..')
        else:
            form = self.change_password_form(user)

        fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': form.base_fields.keys()})]
        adminForm = admin.helpers.AdminForm(form, fieldsets, {})

        context = {
            'title': _('Change password: %s') % escape(user.username),
            'adminForm': adminForm,
            'form_url': mark_safe(form_url),
            'form': form,
            'is_popup': '_popup' in request.REQUEST,
            'add': True,
            'change': False,
            'has_delete_permission': False,
            'has_change_permission': True,
            'has_absolute_url': False,
            'opts': self.model._meta,
            'original': user,
            'save_as': False,
            'show_save': True,
        }
        return TemplateResponse(request, [
            self.change_user_password_template or
            'admin/auth/user/change_password.html'
        ], context, current_app=self.admin_site.name)

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue='../%s/'):
        """
        Determines the HttpResponse for the add_view stage. It mostly defers to
        its superclass implementation but is customized because the User model
        has a slightly different workflow.
        """
        # We should allow further modification of the user just added i.e. the
        # 'Save' button should behave like the 'Save and continue editing'
        # button except in two scenarios:
        # * The user has pressed the 'Save and add another' button
        # * We are adding a user in a popup
        if '_addanother' not in request.POST and '_popup' not in request.POST:
            request.POST['_continue'] = 1
        return super(UserAdmin, self).response_add(request, obj,
                                                   post_url_continue)

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

By deregistering the admin class and reregistering it, you can override the fields it passes into the fieldset of the Edit User page. Hope that helps!

Comment: hey !! I am unable to give superuser option while adding user .. is it possible ?

Answer (score 18):

If you want your superuser to still be able to add other superusers through the admin, but not  allow staff users to manage superusers, you'll need to create a custom admin that overrides the `get_fieldsets` method.  This can go in your `admin.py` file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return self.add_fieldsets

        if request.user.is_superuser:
            perm_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                           'groups', 'user_permissions')
        else:
            # modify these to suit the fields you want your
            # staff user to be able to edit
            perm_fields = ('is_active', 'is_staff')

        return [(None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
                (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
                (_('Permissions'), {'fields': perm_fields}),
                (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})]
```

Follow the procedures to unregister the django User admin and register your new User admin:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

You can do similar things with any model where you want a different set of fieldsets for one set of users versus another -- just override the `get_fieldsets` method in your custom admin and use the request object to determine which user is trying to access it.

Answer (score 14):

Instead of redefine fieldsets, you can also just delete the is_superuser field :

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from copy import deepcopy

class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        fieldsets = super(UserAdmin, self).get_fieldsets(request, obj)
        if not obj:
            return fieldsets

        if not request.user.is_superuser or request.user.pk == obj.pk:
            fieldsets = deepcopy(fieldsets)
            for fieldset in fieldsets:
                if 'is_superuser' in fieldset[1]['fields']:
                    if type(fieldset[1]['fields']) == tuple :
                        fieldset[1]['fields'] = list(fieldset[1]['fields'])
                    fieldset[1]['fields'].remove('is_superuser')
                    break

        return fieldsets

User = get_user_model()
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

The main advantage is that you keep default fieldsets. If django.contrib.admin evolves, you won't need to review your code to modify your fieldsets to stay coherent with default fieldsets.

In this exemple, I also delete the field if the user is editing himself to avoid some losing rights.

Edit : add a deepcopy instruction, else fieldsets update is done for everybody with the first request.user wich exec the code (because an instance can be used by two different user, depending on your web server conf).

Comment: this works for me, but the imports are `from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin` | `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`

Comment: Thx, I fix it. But you should not import User model directly : it can be another model which is used. `get_user_model` avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same question and after some research I prefer the following:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    fields = ["date_joined", "last_login"]
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        fields.append("is_superuser")
    return fields
```

Add this to your custom UserAdmin.